# Is it possible to include .git folder

Tags: windows, git, synchronization, gitignore

I want to put my setting files in to the Git repository so I can sync them between my computers. I have the following folder structure:

```
d:\settings\
 .git
 plugins\
   .git
   other_things\
```

So, `settings` and `plugins` are separate git repositories. To track `plugins` folder without using submodules, I run the following command as per [this](http://debuggable.com/posts/git-fake-submodules:4b563ee4-f3cc-4061-967e-0e48cbdd56cb) post:

```
git add plugins/
```

Everything was fine, I was able to 'see' the files from `plugins` folder within `settings` up until I tried to sync it to my other computer, where `plugins` folder was missing its own `.git` directory.

Is it possible to include (exclude from .gitignore) `.git` folder via `.gitignore` somehow? I tried to use something like:

```
!..\.git
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use submodule or subtree for that purpose. You can read more about submodules here:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule